# Typical scenarios for testing cache in Java

Tags: java, caching

I'm working on 2-level cache (1-st is RAM and 2-nd is FS) in Java. I implemented first level for now.

Could you please clarify:

How to make good testing for my cache implementation?

Which scenarios are typical for using cache in java application?

For now my testing scenario is just 5-20 threads which try to put and get data from cache. 
But I suppose that it's not typical case...

Comment: For objects. It is just learning task, so I don't know how it will be used particularly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to know some statistics about the requests being made in order to properly test it.

You could go ahead and test 3 scenarios where you have a special setup for starters:

**Setup**: 200 MB RAM, 5 GB FS space.

**Test 1**: Only do queries that you *know* are in the RAM.

**Test 2**: Do a percentage queries that you *know* are in the RAM, and the other queries must be fetched from the file system.

**Test 3**: Do 100% requests that you know must be selected from the FS.

If you do these tests, you'll have 3 coordinates that will give you an idea of the performance for each layer. If you want to be more thorough then add 25% and 75% or more increment percentages.

If you have access to some "live testing", meaning real requests that you're trying to speed up, then create some statistics for your requests and base your cache on those instead of trying to solve a general "caching" problem.